# How to determine character encoding in Hyper SQL database

Tags: character-set, encoding, hsqldb

I have Hyper SQL database and I don't know what is current character set. Is it set for whole DB or it can be different for every table? How to evaluate encoding in my base?

Answer (score 2):

HSQLDB stores text data as Unicode. You can verify that by opening the `.script` file for the database and looking at the data.

For example, for a table with a row containing "Montréal" the `.script` file contains

```sql
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.TABLE1(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,TEXTCOL VARCHAR(50))
...
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(1,'Montr\u00e9al')
```

where `\u0039` is the Unicode code point for the letter `é`.